# Why aren't event.lines showing up when using chart.TimeSeries?

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to plot various events over a times series data set using chart.TimeSeries in the PerformanceAnalytics library. I have tried to follow the example from  but I think I am missing something. 
[ExampleChart](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM-files/R_CC/result/PerformanceAnalytics/chart.TimeSeries.Rd_002_large.png) [MyChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYkFA.jpg)

Neither my vertical event lines nor are my period areas are showing up on the chart. My code is almost identical to the example code.  Any ideas?

```
risk.dates = c(
  "2015-04-19"
  )
risk.labels = c(
  "Jon Oliver's Patent Episode "
  )

cycle.dates <- c ("2015-1-01/2015-01-31",
                      "2015-03-01/2015-03-31",
                      "2015-05-01/2015-05-31",
                      "2015-07-01/2015-07-31"
                      )
chart.TimeSeries(df, colorset = "darkblue",
                 date.format.in = "%Y-%m-%d",
                 legend.loc = NULL,
                 period.areas = cycles.dates,
                 period.color = "lightblue",
                 event.lines = risk.dates,
                 event.labels = risk.labels,
                 event.color = "red", lwd = 2,
                 main = "Reddit Sentiment Index",
                 auto.grid = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(DateTime=
          c("2/17/2015","2/18/2015","2/19/2015",
            "2/20/2015","2/21/2015","2/22/2015", 
            "2/23/2015","2/24/2015","2/25/2015",
            "2/26/2015","2/27/2015","2/28/2015",
            "2/28/2015","2/27/2015"),
           AvgSentimentScore=
             c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA",
               "8.405975696","8.313470536","8.414560335",
                "8.720865075","9.284902246"))
```

Comment: may we have a df to work with? [How to help people help you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am kind of new to the StackOverFlow system.  Here is a link to the data frame in Google Sheets.  If there is a better way of sharing, please let me know. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tdiov9IS76YLX2syvTkoHYuVmSlWs83bJnahuduesoQ/edit?usp=sharing